# sklearn Random Forest classifier vs R’s Random Forest classifier

Tags: machine-learning, python, r, random-forest

I’m trying to implement the R’s random forest classifier equivalent in python-

```
## train random forest

set.seed(5136)
ty.rf = randomForest(y=ty.y,
x= ty.x,
ntree=1000,
importance=T,
strata=ty.y,
sampsize=c(100,100),
do.trace=10,
proximity=T)
```

The above classifier was implemented for an imbalanced data.

I had tried to implement the above as following in python.

Here’s my implementation in python -

```
###random forest  

 rf_pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor', preprocessor),
 ('model’,RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=1000,class_weight='balanced', random_state=5136, oob_score=True, bootstrap = True))])  

 rf_pipeline.fit(ty_x, ty_y)
```

Is this the equivalent syntax here? Also, after implementation in R code OOB estimate of error rate: 19.41% and in python OOB estimate of error rate: 7.14%, is this expected? I was expecting the oob_error to be similar. Can someone please clarify?